# Max File Size Downloadable in Background for Windows Phone 8.1 (Universal App)

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I couldn't find this on MSDN, but is there a limit on the maximum file size that can be downloaded by using a BackgroundDownloader DownloadOperation?

I know there is a limit for Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight (20/100MB for cell/wifi), however I could not see anything for Windows Phone 8.1 Universal Apps.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new [BackgroundTransfer API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.aspx) there are no more restrictions.

You can read more [here at the blog](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/05/29/migrating-your-windows-phone-app-from-the-background-transfer-service-to-the-converged-windows-networking-backgroundtransfer-api/):

> No arbitrary file-size restrictions: BTS restricts transfer file sizes based on the network conditions (details here). In BT there are no file-size restrictions; it’s bound only by the amount of free space available on the phone’s internal storage.

Comment: Thanks so much, that's exactly what I wanted to hear.